# How to know which agent is used for running a build definition of Visual Studio TFS 2012?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-definition, build-agent

After executed, a `build definition` remains failed. I want to know which `build agent` was used by the `build controller` that run it.

How can I know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Build Log will say which Agent was used:

[image]